# Column empty or null then fetch value from other table

Tags: postgresql, null, left-join, talend, isnullorempty

[image]

I have a 3 tables in Postgresql. I have a Table C wherein I want the
results from Table A. If the values for region is null/blank from
Table A then I need the region value from Table B. How do I join these
in Postgresql? Or how can this be done in Talend?

Comment: What you have done so far.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(ta.country, tb.country) as country, tc.region 
  FROM tb
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT country, region FROM tablec
  ) tc ON tc.country = tb.country
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT country, region FROM tablea
  ) ta ON ta.country = tb.country
) WHERE country IS NOT NULL AND region IS NOT NULL
```

It will zip all tables together and select the preferred rows then throw away to empty ones. `COALESCE` will select the first non null value from its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In Talend you can use the tMap component where the main input are the rows from TableA and TableC is a lookup table. On the output side you can define the following for the region column:
`StringUtils.convertEmptyToNull(mainrow.region) != null ? mainrow.region : lookuprow:region`